# Parse XML in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, xml-parsing

The variable `@photo` contains this XML:

```
<photo id="2733">
  <urls>
    <url type="photopage">http://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/2733/</url>
  </urls>
</photo>
```

I need to get its url and I tried to do that by  `@photo.urls.url` but I couldn't. How do access http address  `http://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/2733/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the nokogiri gem. Is is made to manipulate xml documents.